# Error : Expecting '}' but was: 'for'

Tags: apex

```
public class TaskOneOpty {
List<opportunity> opp1 = [select id,amount, StageName from opportunity];
List<opportunity> opp2 = new List<opportunity>();
   for (opportunity OP:opp1)
    {
        if (OP.StageName == 'Closed Won')
            {
               OP.amount=OP.account.AnnualRevenue;
                opp2.add(OP); 
            }
    } 
update opp2;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot write code in the body of a class. You must declare a method, constructor, property, or static initializer block.

I suggest reviewing the [Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_understanding.htm) section of the Apex Developer Guide.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define a *method* which will execute this code. You should also always declare some sharing level on every class you ever write.

```
public with sharing class TaskOneOpty
{
    public static void doStuff()
    {
        List<opportunity> opp1 = [select id,amount, StageName from opportunity];
        List<opportunity> opp2 = new List<opportunity>();
        for (opportunity OP:opp1)
        {
            if (OP.StageName == 'Closed Won')
            {
                OP.amount=OP.account.AnnualRevenue;
                opp2.add(OP);
            }
        }
        update opp2;
    }
}
```